# Run an animation on mouse hover over a div?

Tags: jquery, css, animation, hover

I've seen the image below in a website,When you hover mouse on it,The background image changes!

Actually i'm searching for the way to get to this style of animation(the default image slides down then the hover image will slide up!)

Please take look at the following image:

[Click to view the image](http://oi58.tinypic.com/3520xm8.jpg)

What should i use?jQuery,CSS 3?

thanks a lot!

Comment: There's a lot of things you could do, and I mean so many I could probably spend the next half hour enumerating them off the top of my head, but I won't because I see no benefit to you or me if I did.  You will have to invest some time and effort to figure something out.  The simplest solution would probably be to try googling "mouse hover animate" or something and maybe there's a script or something that'd help you out.

Comment: (I see the source of my confusion, which required me to edit my own comment. You had first linked to http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=3520xm8&s=8#.U6d6p_ldVSF before you linked to http://oi58.tinypic.com/3520xm8.jpg )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on what browsers you're looking to support, as well as performance. If it's cross browser perhaps a JavaScript/jQuery solution would be most suitable. If it's mobile audiences, it's safer to go with your CSS3 option.